# Is there a QGIS 3 setting to completely turn off plugins?

Tags: qgis-3

I would like to turn off all plugins without uninstalling them.  I usually do this while testing to rule out an issue being caused by a plugin.  I am looking for the QGIS equivalent to the ArcMap Administrator setting `BlockAddIns` being set to 4:

```
0—Load all add-ins regardless of whether or not they have digital signatures.
1—Only load and use add-ins that are digitally signed by a trusted certificate authority.
2—Only load and use add-ins that have been published by ESRI.
3—Only load add-ins from the administrator folders (described below) and all add-ins published by ESRI.
4—Do not load or execute any add-ins in this application.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When launching QGIS, you can use the command line and use the `--noplugins` option.

See [command line options](https://docs.qgis.org/3.0/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html#command-line-options) for complete documentation.

Also, worth to be listed but not strictly related to the question, you can launch QGIS using a "blank profile" (no plugins and all settings by default), by doing `Settings -> User Profiles -> New Profile…`

Comment: Well, I created a profile with Memory Layer Saver only and one with no plugins. Both were up to the 10-minute mark with fully opening the file. I'll next try re-creating the project file and see if that helps.