# How to prevent plugins from loading at start?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to set plugins to unchecked at start in QGIS-3.10, I thought it could be possible at the "Manage and install plugins" menu; if I uncheck the plugins they disappear from the menu, but whenever I restart they get loaded again, I'm trying with the purpose of a faster start and a cleaner look

Comment: you need start QGIS using this flag `--noplugins`

Answer (score 1):

You could add the command line option `--noplugins` when starting QGIS, see this question: [Is there a QGIS 3 setting to completely turn off plugins?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272772/is-there-a-qgis-3-setting-to-completely-turn-off-plugins)