# Very slow QGIS at own environment level

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layers, windows, general-function-failure

I have had a problem for a long time that I cannot solve. It is about the slowness to operate with any command in QGIS. I'm not talking about very heavy projects, but about the QGIS environment itself.

When selecting any tool, selecting any layer in the layer panel, and even trying to open a project becomes very slow; I always get the message, QGIS No response (No response).

I add that it is not a problem with the performance of the PC, because in the ones I test it, they are quite powerful: 32GB RAM, i7; independent graphics card, SSD etc. I'm talking about laptops. I do not know if it could be due to some update of Windows itself; or that some other software is interfering; for example, have Python, 3.7 and 3.9 installed and running in other apps. I add that the computer where I am looking now is very well configured and with very few packages of other things installed; I mean, PC not overloaded at all. The performances of the same are normal in terms of RAM, processor, etc.

I know that it is not a problem of the QGIS itself, but of the whole, but I do not know how to determine where the incompatibility comes from. I have located other people who have the same problem, but at the moment we have been unable to resolve this issue.

I also point out that I have tried several versions, from LTR 3.16 to the current 3.20.
Every time I install a new version, I eliminate the previous one even at the Windows level and eliminate any trace of third-party plugins, that is, I leave QGIS "virgin" in all its installation; same problem persists.

What could or could we do? Do you know something about it?

Comment: Check the accepted answers in these previous questions for possible solutions (e.g. creating new profile and hiding network drives). https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403343/what-can-be-a-reason-of-qgis-slow-work  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367591/how-to-fix-qgis-being-extremely-slow