# Is there a way to analyze/solve internet related QGIS lag?

Tags: qgis

My QGIS startup time and response time (after minimizing/switching tasks) is significantly delayed, only when I am connected to the internet. As soon as I disconnect from Internet, all loading becomes almost instanteneous.

E.g. I start QGIS, it loads for minutes, but when I disconnect, it loads immediately. Or: I minimize QGIS and after a few minutes try to use it again, but get only a blank screen, loading for minutes until it shows all UI. But when I disconnect from internet, it is back and responsive immediately.

My insights so far:

- **Debugging/Development Tools** show, that the "Main Window" is responsible for startup delay e.g. 500 seconds or more (and probably also the unresponsive behavior). But I don't know how to drill down what exactly in the "Main Window" is causing the lag (see image below).
- This was reproducible with **QGIS LTR 3.28.11** and still is after the
  recent upgrade to **QGIS LTR 3.34.4**.
- Switching to a **clean/new user profile** (without plugins and so on) has no effect (besides the reduced plugin load time, but the long delay isn't caused by that)
- I am aware of **network drives** that can be the source of slowdown. In fact they were at some point for me, since we have company network drives P: / U:. These cause long lags and unresponsive behavior when not in VPN with fast internet (in Windows generally, and also in QGIS with all browser/load file based operations), but I could fix that for QGIS by removing P: and U: from searchable drives (by modifying the .ini). Also that doesn't seem to be the reason here, since the long load times remain even if in a fast VPN environment (that has access to internet).
- I generally find QGIS a bit sluggish when it comes to loading network layers. I think the network requests shouldn't slow down the main UI, but should run asynchronous to all other tasks, leaving a responsive UI despite of e.g. WMS/WMTS layers being loaded or not... in an attempt to achieve faster response times I lowered the **timeout for network requests**, however that is always a trade-off between long load times with unresponsive behavior and dropping network requests up to the extent that nothing is loaded at all for slow connections [image: Timeout for Network Request setting]
- I also read through these threads, without finding anything that helps:
  [What can be a reason of QGIS slow work?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403343/what-can-be-a-reason-of-qgis-slow-work) and
  [How to fix QGIS being extremely slow?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367591/how-to-fix-qgis-being-extremely-slow)

Does anyone else experience similar problems?
Any suggestions on what else to try?

[image: Main Window]

Comment: you can try sysinternals `procmon` or `fiddler` to see what resource is being requested.

Comment: What kind of datasets are you accessing over the internet by vpn?  I found that file geodatabase layers were problematic in both ArcGIS and QGIS, so I only used local versions of them.  Shapefiles worked much better.

Comment: @John: During the described behavior I am not accessing anything via VPN (simply starting the locally installed QGIS without a project and/or opening a local project).

Comment: @JGH: thanks for the suggestion, I tried `procmon` right now and filtered for Process Name qgis. I get a lot (as in thousands) of entries with many details, any additional hints what I am looking for exactly? Operations mostly revolve around RegQueryKey and Query/Read/Close File/Directory; Results are mostly SUCCESS, with a few REPARSE/NAME NOT FOUND/BUFFER OVERFLOW here and there. But I don't have a conclusive lead rightaway (as in specific network paths that time out or URLs being requested...)