# QGIS 3.10.3 processing import problems

Tags: api, library

I just updated QGIS from 3.10.2 to 3.10.3. When I start QGIS I receive this message log in processing tab:

> 2020-02-24T14:27:00     CRITICAL    Could not import script algorithm
>   'quick_api' from
>   '/home/federico/old_lacie/federico/qgis/pyqt/quick_api/quick_api.py'
>                attempted relative import with no known parent package.

and this message log in Error Python tab:

> 2020-02-24T14:27:00     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
>                 File "/app/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptAlgorithmProvider.py",
>   line 119, in loadAlgorithms
>                 alg = ScriptUtils.loadAlgorithm(moduleName, filePath)
>                 File "/app/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptUtils.py",
>   line 66, in loadAlgorithm
>                 spec.loader.exec_module(module)
>                 File "", line 728, in exec_module
>                 File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>                 File "/home/federico/old_lacie/federico/qgis/pyqt/quick_api/plugin_upload.py",
>   line 13, in 
>                 standard_library.install_aliases()
>                NameError: name 'standard_library' is not defined

and processing works bad.
I suppose same variable settings has changed, but I didn't find which are.

Comment: run QGIS with no plugins (there looks like an incompatible plugin quick_api) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272772/is-there-a-qgis-3-setting-to-completely-turn-off-plugins

Comment: I disabled every plugin. Then I start QGIS and try to enable processing. I receive a message of error in a distinct window ("NameError: name 'standard_library' is not defined "). Then QGIS crashes !!!!

Comment: I already tried to remove and reinstall QGIS via software app and via shell, with the same result.

Comment: I created a new user profile. Then I renamed the directory "default" and "new_user_profile" each other. I know: it's not scientific. But it works; now processing is loaded.