# QGIS GUI not starting

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Recently, I installed QGIS 3.10.14. I tried to start the application but QGIS would not start after the "setting up GUI" and "Starting Python". I also tried to uninstall QGIS and python from my system and Reinstall them again but still, the problem is not solved.

How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Try deleting your QGIS profile (make a backup before). It is located in C:/users/username/appdata/roaming/qgis (on windows)

Comment: Still facing the same issue.

Comment: try in command line with the option --noplugins https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272772/is-there-a-qgis-3-setting-to-completely-turn-off-plugins

Comment: Still unable to get it started