Python Error on QGIS 3.34.X
I installed QGIS on my computer but it encounter a python error as show below.
I am not an expert on GIS.

2024-06-21T15:19:19     WARNING    Python error : Couldn't load plugin
'rastertool' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method
See message log (Python Error) for more details.


Have you installed a rastertools plugin? Because if yes that's a known bug of the plugin. See https://github.com/aishwaryahegde29/RasterTool_Qgis/issues/2 . Try uninstalling the plugin.

launch qgis in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272772/is-there-a-qgis-3-setting-to-completely-turn-off-plugins command line and use the --noplugins option

It's not a bug, it's that the OP hasn't got the python libraries required by the plugin installed. Actually, having had a look at the plugin, I wouldn't use it at all. It's completely undocumented and has not been updated for 5 years.

Dear @TomazicM thank you for your response. Everything is working as usual now that I've uninstalled RasterTools.
