NetWorkErrorException when running QuickOSM plugin in QGIS
I can't run the QuickOSM plugin in QGIS. I have tried reinstalling the plugin but it doesn't work
This is the log from Python error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/LISBETH/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\quick_osm_processing\quickosm_process.py", line 444, in processAlgorithm
return self.process_road(context, url)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users/LISBETH/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\quick_osm_processing\quickosm_process.py", line 138, in process_road
osm_file = connexion_overpass_api.run()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users/LISBETH/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\core\api\connexion_oapi.py", line 85, in run
raise NetWorkErrorException('Overpass API', ', '.join(self.errors))
QuickOSM.core.exceptions.NetWorkErrorException: Overpass API : Download failed: Connection closed

Execution failed after 39.34 seconds


create a new profile in qgis - or use safe mode (no plugins) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272772/is-there-a-qgis-3-setting-to-completely-turn-off-plugins
